# In svelte 3 is the $: reactive statement declaration slower or faster than HTML element class attribute? How can I measure it effectively?

Tags: performance, benchmarking, svelte, svelte-3, microbenchmark

Since I am building a series of components that will be updated several times per second and in large quantities I was wondering if there was a difference in FPS between the first solution below and the second:

- First one (HTML element class)

  ```
  <script>
      export let className = undefined

      export let something = false
      export let somethingelse = false
  </script>

  <div class={`myCustomClass1 myCustomClass2 ${something ? "myCustomClass3" : "myCustomClass4"}${somethingelse ? "myCustomClass5" : "myCustomClass6"}${className ? ` ${className}` : ""}`}
  >
      Hello!
  </div>
  ```
- Second one ($: reactive statement):

  ```
  <script>
      export let className = undefined

      export let something = false
      export let somethingelse = false

      $: classes = "myCustomClass1 myCustomClass2${something ? "myCustomClass3" : "myCustomClass4"}${somethingelse ? "myCustomClass5" : "myCustomClass6"}${className ? ` ${className}` : ""} 
  </script>

  <div class={classes}>Hello!</div>
  ```

Basically: **is the `$:` reactive statement declaration slower than HTML element `class` attribute?**

How can I measure it effectively?

Comment: If you are woried about the code, you can always dive into the compiled code. For instance the Svelte Repl gives you the JS output. And .. more here: https://lihautan.com/compile-svelte-in-your-head-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to comment because this will not directly answer your question, but I don't have enough rep

to bind a class to a variable, svelte has this, it might be more practical for you :

```
<script>
  export let classIsActive = false;
  export let evenShorter = false;
</script>


<div
  class:activateClass={classIsActive}
  class:evenShorter
  class:combinationClass={classIsActive && evenShorter}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you. But as you can see I have a lot of strings there! LOL! I'll think about it tough!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I think that there is no difference in performance on both methods because for both methods every time the props get updated the class attribute need to be recalculated.

However, I prefer using `$: classes = ...` cause it increases the readability of the code, also you may need to declare a function that handles the logic of building class attribute, for example:

```
export function classNames(...args){
    return args.map(arg=>{
        if(Array.isArray(arg)){
            if(arg.length === 1){
                return arg[0]
            }
            
            return arg[0] ?arg[1] :arg[2]||''
        }
        return arg
    }).join(' ')
}
```

App.svelte

```
<script>
    import {classNames} from './classNames'
    
    export let className = undefined
  export let something = false
  export let somethingelse = false
  
    $:classnames = classNames("myCustomClass1 myCustomClass2", [something, "myCustomClass3", "myCustomClass4"], [somethingelse, "myCustomClass5","myCustomClass6"], [className])
</script>

<div class={classnames}>
    Hello!
</div>
```